# Where To Put C# Compiled Library DLLs

Tags: winforms, dll, ribbon

I've compiled the RibbonLib, then I got two DLLs(`Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll` and `Ribbon.dll`), but where I need to put this DLLs to use they in my Visual Studio 2008?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, if it's needed. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solution explorer, right click on project and then click "Add Reference", go to the "Browser" tab and add "Ribbon.dll".

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of the [Windows Ribbon for WinForms](http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/) does not depends on the Windows API Code Pack. So you can just add the Ribbon.dll to the references section.